# Unable to setup Jenkins agent on docker

Tags: docker, jenkins, jnlp, jenkins-agent

I'm trying to create agent on docker by using the below command but it returned exception

```
:~$ docker run jenkins/jnlp-slave -disableHttpsCertValidation -url https://hostName/CI-KINDLE-1924  774351357f93a1026afasdfagsg180551cca56a9cfa741234531fsdfdee8feeb dockerslave
```

**Exception:**

Observed the below exception in console:

> INFO: Protocol JNLP4-connect encountered an unexpected exception
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
> org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.ConnectionRefusalException:
> Unknown client name: dockerslave
> at org.jenkinsci.remoting.util.SettableFuture.get(SettableFuture.java:223)
> at hudson.remoting.Engine.innerRun(Engine.java:614)
> at hudson.remoting.Engine.run(Engine.java:474) Caused by: org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.ConnectionRefusalException:
> Unknown client name: dockerslave
> at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.ConnectionHeadersFilterLayer.newAbortCause(ConnectionHeadersFilterLayer.java:378)
> at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.ConnectionHeadersFilterLayer.onRecvClosed(ConnectionHeadersFilterLayer.java:433)
> at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.ProtocolStack$Ptr.onRecvClosed(ProtocolStack.java:816)
> at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.FilterLayer.onRecvClosed(FilterLayer.java:287)
> at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.SSLEngineFilterLayer.onRecvClosed(SSLEngineFilterLayer.java:172)

When I tried to connect through "Web Launch agent from browser" using below command It connected successfully.

```
java -jar agent.jar -jnlpUrl https://hostName/CI-KINDLE-1924/computer/Worker/slave-agent.jnlp -secret 774351357f93a1026afasdfagsg180551cca56a9cfa741234531fsdfdee8feeb -workDir "/x/home/achu"
```

The above command works as expected and the agent will be active. But I just want to create slave nodes in docker and wanna activate them at runtime and destroy.

Please anyone help me to achieve this

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I just added my slave node name as client name and it worked.

I just created a slave node in Jenkins master and I just used the name It works perfectly fine.